# Obtener Dias, horas, minutos y segundo en SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Hola buen dia como puedo obtener un resultado como el siguiente:

```
fechainicio:2017-08-14 15:00:00 fechatermino: 2017-08-15 17:30:00 quisiera obtenerlo en este formato como resultado:

1 día, 2 horas y 30 minutos,
```

tengo la consulta asi :

```
DATEDIFF (Hour, CONVERT(DATETIME, DOCTO_REFE.C8) + CONVERT(DATETIME, DOCTO_REFE.C9), CONVERT(DATETIME, DOCTO_PROCESADO.C8) + CONVERT(DATETIME, DOCTO_PROCESADO.C9))  % 24 As Horas,
    DATEDIFF (Minute, CONVERT(DATETIME, DOCTO_REFE.C8) + CONVERT(DATETIME, DOCTO_REFE.C9), CONVERT(DATETIME, DOCTO_PROCESADO.C8) + CONVERT(DATETIME, DOCTO_PROCESADO.C9)) % 60 As Minutos,
    DATEDIFF (Second, CONVERT(DATETIME, DOCTO_REFE.C8) + CONVERT(DATETIME, DOCTO_REFE.C9), CONVERT(DATETIME, DOCTO_PROCESADO.C8) + CONVERT(DATETIME, DOCTO_PROCESADO.C9))  % 60 As Segundos,
```

pero si son: 11:59:20 y 12:10:48 me pone una 1 hora 11 minutos y 28 segundos del mismo dio se supone
que solo han pasado los 11 minutos y 28 segundos como puedo evitar esto?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dejo la consulta que utilizaría yo. Realmente es importante tener columnas con tipos de datos correctos para evitar tener que estar haciendo conversiones constantes. Toda la explicación está en los comentarios del código.

```
SELECT  --Primero obtenemos los días, obteniendo la diferencia desde una fecha base
          CONVERT( VARCHAR(5), DATEDIFF( dd, 0, DATEADD( SS, DATEDIFF(SS, x.FechaInicio, x.FechaFinal), 0))) + ' d ' 
          --Luego obtenemos juntos todos los elementos de la hora
        + STUFF( STUFF( STUFF( --Estas funciones permiten reemplazar los signos normales del tiempo con h/m/s
            CONVERT( varchar( 10), DATEADD( SS, DATEDIFF(SS, x.FechaInicio, x.FechaFinal), 0), 114) --Usamos convert para que de el formato de solo tiempo
                , 9, 5, ' s'), 6, 1, ' m '), 3, 1, ' h ') --Reemplazamos de derecha a izquierda para que sea más fácil contar
--El FROM y CROSS JOIN no son parte de la solución, solo están para generar datos de prueba
FROM        (SELECT C8 = '20170813', C9 = '18:00:05') DOCTO_REFE 
CROSS JOIN  (SELECT C8 = '20170815', C9 = '17:30:00') DOCTO_PROCESADO
--El CROSS APPLY nos permite simplificar el código que utilizamos en las fórmulas
CROSS APPLY (SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, DOCTO_REFE.C8) + CONVERT(DATETIME, DOCTO_REFE.C9) AS FechaInicio,
                     CONVERT(DATETIME, DOCTO_PROCESADO.C8) + CONVERT(DATETIME, DOCTO_PROCESADO.C9) AS FechaFinal) x;
```

Comment: Muchas gracias @Luis Cazares me sirvio mucho esta mejor estructurada que la que subi, me sirvio mucho, gracias

Answer (score 0):

al final me funciono algo como lo siguiente:

```
CONVERT(varchar(4), FLOOR(FLOOR(DATEDIFF(mi, CONVERT(DATETIME, DOCTO_REFE.C8) + CONVERT(DATETIME, DOCTO_REFE.C9), CONVERT(DATETIME, DOCTO_PROCESADO.C8) + CONVERT(DATETIME, DOCTO_PROCESADO.C9))/60.0)/24.0)) + ' d ' +
        CONVERT(varchar(2), FLOOR(DATEDIFF(mi, CONVERT(DATETIME, DOCTO_REFE.C8) + CONVERT(DATETIME, DOCTO_REFE.C9), CONVERT(DATETIME, DOCTO_PROCESADO.C8) + CONVERT(DATETIME, DOCTO_PROCESADO.C9))/60.0 % 24)) + ' h ' +
        CONVERT(varchar(2), DATEDIFF(mi, CONVERT(DATETIME, DOCTO_REFE.C8) + CONVERT(DATETIME, DOCTO_REFE.C9), CONVERT(DATETIME, DOCTO_PROCESADO.C8) + CONVERT(DATETIME, DOCTO_PROCESADO.C9)) % 60) + ' m ' +
        convert(varchar(10), (((DATEDIFF (Second, CONVERT(DATETIME, DOCTO_REFE.C8) + CONVERT(DATETIME, DOCTO_REFE.C9), CONVERT(DATETIME, DOCTO_PROCESADO.C8) + CONVERT(DATETIME, DOCTO_PROCESADO.C9))%86400)%3600)%60)) + ' s' AS TIEMPOPROCESA,
```

Comment: Considera explicar tu código